# T4MVC VB with Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, t4mvc

I am having trouble using T4MVC VB with Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition.

I can reference the T4MVC classes in my controllers, but I cannot access them in my views (where I actually need them).

In the view, the following code is overwritten by intellisense as if the class `MVC` is invalid.

```
MVC.Home.GameBoard
```

It is replaced with

```
Mvc.Home.GameBoard
```

Which generates the error message `'Home' is not a member of 'Mvc'`.  It seems that in the view there is an `Mvc` namespace hiding the `MVC` class.  This doesn't exist in the controller.  How can I make this work?

**Update:** After playing with it some more, it seems the classes aren't available in the View no matter what they're named.  What decides what classes and namespaces are available in the view?  The classes continue to be available in the controller, regardless of naming as well.  I presume there has to be some filter or limit on what is available in the views?

**Update:** I was just watching [this excellent video](https://stackoverflow.com/users/598/haacked) from [Phil Haack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/598/haacked), and it game me a clue.

I need to modify the `<pages>` section in the web.config file.  Now the question is, can I get that to use a class that's not in a namespace, as the MVC class is by default, otherwise I'll have to modify the T4 template to put it in a namespace and include that.

Comment: Have u Imported T4Mvc class in your view? or check that Views and  and genrated T4mvc class is in same namespace?

Comment: @swapneel how do I import it into the view?  I don't see import statements in any of the other views.  Additionally, I don' think I can import it, b/c the MVC class isn't generated in a namespace.

Comment: You are right - i just cheked that in my test code. MVC.Home.GameBoard is a action link isnt it? try MVC.Home.GameBoard()      <%: Html.ActionLink("Home", MVC.Home.Actions.Index())%>

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're running into some kind of name conflict due to the fact that VB is case insensitive (unlike C#).

Please try going in T4MVC.settings.t4 and change HelpersPrefix from "MVC" to something else that doesn't conflict (e.g. "MyMvc").  Then change your code to use that prefix instead of MVC.

Hopefully that's all it'll take!

Comment: I changed the prefix to `AMVC2` (which obviously doesn't conflict), and still no luck.